# Find $x$ and $y$ such that $2x45y$ is divisible by $72$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm quite lost with this one. I have thought of decomposing $72$ in factors and then applying some property, but I don't remember what. Can anyone explain to me how to solve this?

Comment: $72=8\cdot9$. What are the divisibility rules for $8$ and $9$?

Comment: @DonThousand For 8 it has to be divisible by both 2 and 4... I think. For 9 the sum of the digits has to be 0 in mod 9

Comment: @DonThousand How did you decompose it in 8*9?

Comment: $4$ is divisible by $2$ and $4$...

Comment: $72=8\cdot9$. Basic multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

An integer is divisible by $8$ if and only if the three-digits number formed by its last three decimal digits are divisible by $8$, whence the congruence equation 
 $$ [45y]_{10}\equiv 0\mod 8 \iff [5y]_{10}\equiv 0 \mod 8. $$
Also the standard criterion of divisibility by $9$ yields here 
$$2+x+y\equiv 0\mod 9.$$

Comment: Can a number be divisible by 4 but not 8?

Comment: Why, yes, of course! I just recall that divisibility by $8$ is seen from the last three decimal digits.